# How to add items into an Array Generic Object from the parameter in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

So, I am creating a generic data structure named "Sack". In this I add items to a sack, grab a random item, see if it's empty, or dump out its contents etc. Also I'm creating it to expand to hold as many items as needed.

Currently, I'm working on the add method and I'm having troubles on my add method, and I am trying to think of a way adding what's in my parameter into the sack.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sack<E>
{
    public static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
    private E [] elementData;
    private int size;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Sack()
    {
        elementData = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Sack(int capacity)
    {
        if(capacity < 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity " + capacity);
        }
        this.elementData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if(size == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public E [] dump()
{
   E [] E2 = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      elementData[i] = null;

   }
   size = 0;
    return E2;
}
```

In this method, I am trying to add item, into my sack. When I run my tests, I am told it's incorrect. If there's a way to improve this.

```
    public void add(E item)
    {
        elementData[size] = item;
        size++;
    }
```

elementData is what I am adding the items into.

*Update*

I updated my add method to look like this.

```
public void add(E item)
{
        if(size >= elementData.length-1)
        {
            elementData[size] = item;
            size++;
        }
}
```

The message I am now receiving is that add is not working correctly and to check size usage.

Comment: I'm not sure what your tests are, but you should probably throw a `RuntimeException` in the `add(...)` method if `size >= capacity`.

Comment: @JaceJMcPherson could you show me. I'm confused on this.

Comment: I don't know what your tests are. The code you wrote looks fine, but if you have a `capacity` of 1, and you have already added an item (that is to say, `size == 1`), then adding another item will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It's likely this is the problem you're facing with your tests, but you'll need to be more specific about what those are.

Comment: @JaceJMcPherson I would receive an error with the "if size >= capacity" since capacity isn't in there.

Comment: Indeed, it is simple enough to keep track of the capacity. Create a class variable. You can even compare against `elementData.length` if you want.

Comment: @JaceJMcPherson the message I'm receiving is that my sack array element order incorrect.

Comment: Check the logic of your `add` method.  That test looks wrong to me.

Comment: @StephenC I'm looking at it. Do you suggest a for loop on the add method? Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: No.  I am saying that the test in the `add` code you added in your update to the Q is just wrong.  Plain and simple.  And that causes elements to not be added to the `Sack`.  Read your code carefully, and think about it.

Comment: I would also note that while you say *"I'm creating it to expand to hold as many items as needed"*, you don't appear to have implemented the code to do that (yet).

Comment: @StephenC right, I just left some of my code out, since some of it was unnecessary since it's long. I'll take a look at it. If anything, I'll update it in hopes it helps.

Comment: Only add it if it is relevant to your actual question.  I raised this because I suspected that you might think that your `add` method dealt with that requirement.  (It clearly doesn't.  But that's "clear to me" ... not necessarily "clear to you".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot ensure capacity of Java arrays, Javascript can! You can create a new one and copy:

```
public void add(E element) {

    int index = size++;
    if(size >= elementData.length-1) {

        // it ensures elementData
        elementData = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
    }
    elementData[index] = element;
}
```

or skip ensure of array capacity and change the check direction:

```
public void add(E element) {

    if(size < elementData.length-1) {

        elementData[size++] = element;
    }
    // TODO else notice of the unsuccessfull add
}
```

Comment: I know this is asking for a lot, but if you could check out my remove method on my other question and ensure one it would help, since you knew how to do this one.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it(:

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there's a spec for what your Sack is supposed to do that you did not paste.

It also sounds like your add method is supposed to just work, even if the sack is already at capacity.

That means you need to make a new array, copy over all elements, and then replace the array you have in your Sack instance with the new one (because java arrays cannot grow or shrink).

Look at the source of of java's own ArrayList for a hint on how that's done.

Answer (score 0):

So after numerous tries, I give credit to @rockfarkas for solving this. I put in the following code and it solved my add method code.

```
public void add(E item)
{
    int index = size++;
    if(size >= elementData.length-1)
    {
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
    }
    elementData[index] = item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing this,

```
public void add(E item) 
{
    ensureCapacity(size+1);
    elementData[size] = item;
    size++;
}
```

This also works, but I would have to modify the ensureCapacity method accurately, which I have.